# Android setting up gradle build with dependancies

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I'm trying to set up a project to build with gradle, i've not used it before so I've cobbled together what I read on android tools.  I just want to be able to build the project via Main app with all its dependancies.

When i try and build from app and compile dependancies I get an exception:
* What went wrong:
Main Manifest missing from /Users/seren/Dropbox/codes/androids/mixcloud-work/android/Android/mixcloud/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

However if I take out the dependanices line for other modules, it will start compiling, until it inevitably fails: `compile project(':actionbarsherlock')`

EDIT - SO i made a test project consisting of two modules.  If I start out with the flat hierarchy i get the issue described.  However if i then move the submodule inside the main app module, the project builds no problems. I would like to keep a flat hierarchy though.

My project structure is :

Main app
ActionBarSherlock
Facebook SDK
Utils - java only

So I've set up a build.gradle file in each project directory as follows:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files (
            '../../libs/android-support-v4.jar',
    )
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

}
```

Then with things like the utils that have more dependancies on modules like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files (
            'libs/android-support-v4.jar',
            'libs/gson-2.2.2jar',
    )

    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may missing the `settings.gradle` file located in the root of your project.
You need to specify there which folders are gradle projects :

`include ':app', ':facebook', ':actionbarsherlock'`