# How to set Android v3.0.1 in my gradle script?

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I am using gradle to manage my dependecies in my Android Project. In accordance with the facebook developers  (https://developers.facebook.com/android/), currently the sdk version is 3.0.1. But searching for its dependency in the maven repository (http://mvnrepository.com/), I didn't find this version. Anyone can help me?

I just want to use this android sdk version in my project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in your terms: not Android v3.0.1, but Facebook Android SDK v3.0.1. Facebook provides source code as is. You have to add it as a subproject to your gradle project.
Check this [SO-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594067/android-setting-up-gradle-build-with-dependancies/16857708#16857708)